Power BI Deneb | PBI-David Organizational Tree Chart Update to Show KPI numbers
I'm really enjoying @davidebacci's Power BI deneb visual (https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase/tree/main/Organisation%20Tree%20Chart and it has almost everything I want from it. However, I would like to show the sum of the kpi number for that intersection. I tried exploring it by adding signals, and values but I might be making a rookie mistake.
In addition, in a real world example, some people may not have a kpi associated. How can I update the tree to only return nodes where the value is not blank?
I would like to see associated sum of the kpi measure value level just right on top of the count of children and only return only the children where kpi value is not blank.
Current values:

Expected values:

Shown here is an example of the quantitative sum I wish to see on each tree.
By the way, the calculation on the measure is a basic:
sum = SUM(data[kpi])


to solve my issue, I created a new mark and a new DAX measure to feed it into the visual. It was easier to calculate there instead of within Deneb. I created a parent-child path
Aggregate By Parent = 
VAR _id = SELECTEDVALUE('data'[childId])
RETURN
CALCULATE([sum], ALLSELECTED('data'), PATHCONTAINS('data'[Path], _id))

Output returned from new aggregated measure:

And then I found a filter criteria within deneb that said if my kpi value was blank don't show.
I'd be still interested in being able to achieve this within Deneb though!
